# Invariance Model: Scarla, CFI=1?

Tags: invariance

[CFI reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aflkt.png)

I ran the invariance model with 6 experimental group.  While the metric model is slightly worse than the configural model, the scalar suddenly move to another direction with CFI being 1. see the screenshot.

```
`config <- cfa(model3,
              data=MasterDataMay_7Final,
              group="Group") `

`metric <- cfa(model3,
              data=MasterDataMay_7Final,
              group="Group",group.equal="loadings" )`

`Scalar <-cfa(model3,
             data=MasterDataMay_7Final,
             group="Group",group.equal="loadings","intercepts" )`
```

Given Scalar is a just identified model, I can go ahead and compare means right?

Confirm no problem with the current coding and that I can move ahead for mean comparison